# What is the meaning of this phrase - "So take aim and fire away" in Alan Walker's 'On My Way'?

Tags: american-english, indian-english

So take aim and fire away

I've never been so wide awake

No, nobody but me can keep me safe

And I'm on my way

Comment: It appears to be literal:  Aim a gun at it and fire when you want to.  Is there any reason to suppose it means something else.  Remember "Lyrics are not typical of normal English Prose"!

Comment: I just looked the song up real quick and from the rest of the lyrics I would interpret the phrase figuratively. What's being aimed and fired seems to be hurtful commments or criticism about the singer's lifestyle or decisions. I'd be interested to see what some professional writers/poets might think though :)

Comment: Note that song lyrics do not necessarily mean anything, or any one thing. Lyricists, poets, and others are accorded wide artistic license; the words may simply be intended to evoke certain imagery or emotions, or be chosen to fit a certain pattern of rhythm or rhyme. Other sites, like Genius.com or SongMeanings.net, are better-suited to discussion of the meanings of lyrics, as Stack Exchange is designed to answer questions that have definitive answers.

Answer (score 2):

The song uses the phrase metaphorically. The singer is feeling strong, confident, determined, ready to conquer the world, ready to deal with any problems in her way.

The singer is inviting any person - or inviting the world - to oppose her. She is ready to fight and win. She is *eager* to face any challenge that you put in her way, she is eager to face any challenge that life puts in her way.

A similar phrase is "Bring it on". When used in a business context, a sporting context, or other peaceful context, it means I am ready and eager to deal with any opponent or difficult challenge. However when "Bring it on" is said in a hostile encounter it is literally an invitation for the other person to physically attack. It means I welcome a fistfight.

Comment: +1 especially for "bring it on".    Another similar taunt is *"Take your best shot"*.